# Jazz vinyl, possibly French, male and female singers, non-lexical vocables

Tags: identify-this-song, jazz

So I can only really describe this song...I have tried everything over several days and I think it may be the death of me.

It is a group of singers like some male and female all singing at different and the same times. The only lyrics are 'do dobedobedod waoo waoo do dobedobedodo ba dobedobedobedo' which is utter gibberish. It is mellow and jazz sounding. I heard it around 10 years ago but on vinyl so it really could be anything. I have a feeling it is French or something. The voices in it act sort of percussively in the way they sing.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of the exact song, but it sounds like the ["Swingle Singers"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Swingle_Singers), a long-running French acapella group known for their jazzy covers of classical music.  They first formed in 1962, so you could have easily heard old vinyl of them.

[Swingle Singer - Prelude in F](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kGGm85XqAew)
[Swingle Singers - Libertango](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-uiG5jJavTU?t=1m)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but no it is a lot older than that and does have instruments in...I know I have mine no information but maybe one day I will work it out Haha!

Comment: It could still potentially be the Swingle Singers.  They've been around for 50 years, and have done collabs with instrumental groups --for instance this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kGGm85XqAew